# Any tool to create configmap from a git repo containing configuration files?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm using **Kubernetes-1.8.2** and we want to keep our services' configurations in a git repo, one file per service.

Is there a tool/way to create configmap out of this git repo and watches for changes to update configmaps? Something similar to https://github.com/breser/git2consul but for Kubernetes.

Comment: You can try `kustomize`. https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a tool/way to create configmap out of this git repo and
> watches for changes to update configmaps?

**Option : 1**

By this if you mean just updating the **configmap** and applying the YAML files on git-repo you can use the *[Flux](https://fluxcd.io/)* setup to sync the files to the **K8s cluster**.

Whenever any commit will happen to the **Git** repo, the **flux** will sync the files to the **K8s cluster** and it will apply the **configmap/service/deployment etc** for you from the **YAML configuration** files stored in repo.

Setup the Flux in the K8s cluster once controller PODs are up & running in **flux-system** namespace

You can use below config to set the Gitrepo to watch, you might have to use the **Auth** option if private repo

```
apiVersion: source.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta2
kind: GitRepository
metadata:
  name: my-repo
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 1m
  url: https://github.com/xxxx/url
  ref:
    branch: main
---
apiVersion: kustomize.toolkit.fluxcd.io/v1beta2
kind: Kustomization
metadata:
  name: service-1
  namespace: flux-system
spec:
  interval: 1m0s
  path: config-files #folder on repo storing YAML files
  prune: true
  sourceRef:
    kind: GitRepository
    name: my-repo
  targetNamespace: default
```

Flux will auto-apply the YAML config files and create **configmap/deployment/service** to the cluster whenever a commit happen or on a regular interval if you want to do it.

**Option : 2**

If you want the **Content** to be Inside of POD when the commit happens.

Add shell script inside the **Application deployment** job which code to Git clone the data only.

```
#!/bin/sh
git clone https://<user-name>:<password>@github.com/xxxx/xx
```

You can invoke this Shell script from **Cronjob** inside k8s on regular time.

Webhook server running which will run **child** process **kubectl** create job out of cronjob, create docker image of below code and deploy service to K8s and **expose** it so Github can hit this when **commit** happen and use the **kubectl** as **child** process and execute **shell script** already POD, which will clone data from Git directly to **POD**

```
const express = require("express");
const routes = require("./routes");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exec = util.promisify(childp.exec);
import childp from 'child_process';
import util from 'util';
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
const port = process.env.PORT || "8080";
app.set("port", port);
app.post('/', (req, res) => {
```

})
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on localhost:${port}`));

Function for child process

```
(async () => {
  const { stdout, stderr } = await exec('kubectl exec -it <pod name> -- sh data/pull.sh');
  console.log('stdout:', stdout);
  console.log('stderr:', stderr);
})();
```

Invoke when **Commit** occurs to Git you can leverage the webhook, From Git you can invoke the API of the K8s API server and create the Job resource, this Job will invoke the Shell script already inside the deployment POD, which will clone data from Git repo.

**Option : 3**

You can use the **initcontainer** to clone the **Gitrepo** to volume and mount the same volume to deployment POD.

You can use the [Keel](https://keel.sh/) which will monitor the Git and based on the policy it will **roll update** the **Deployment**. So whenever there is no new it will update the new PODs and the init container will download repo content.

This will be a little bit more controlled option and will update **all** the **PODs** if you are running **multiple** under the **deployment**.

Answer (score 0):

No that I'm aware of. But unless you want to create it yourself, you could try to find a solution using https://github.com/kubernetes/git-sync, which is a sidecar app which clones a git repo and keeps it in sync with the upstream.

> git-sync is a simple command that pulls a git repository into a local directory. It is a perfect "sidecar" container in Kubernetes - it can periodically pull files down from a repository so that an application can consume them.
>
> git-sync can pull one time, or on a regular interval. It can pull from the HEAD of a branch, or from a git tag, or from a specific git hash. It will only re-pull if the target of the run has changed in the upstream repository. When it re-pulls, it updates the destination directory atomically. In order to do this, it uses a git worktree in a subdirectory of the --root and flips a symlink.

Comment: Thanks @fuinchinho. I was trying to avoid sidecar for this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get the files in a git repository you can also use a `initContainer` and use `emptyDir` mount volume that this container will populate. It can close your repo and populate the directory. You deployment/pod can mount this volume and it will always have the data.

You get fresh copy of data every-time you restart your pod or scale your pod.